# bash - Copy and rename file to higher directory, to new file type

Tags: bash

I am still learning bash, but this should be easy. I want to copy a file from a temp folder to a higher directory, and change the name.

`home/temp/oldfile` to `home/newfile.txt`

`oldfile` has no specific file type, and it's name is adjusted on a daily basis. So, I would like to copy whichever file is in `home/temp` and paste it as .txt.  The temp folder contains only 1 file.

**Command so far**

`cp /home/temp/. /home/newfile.txt -R`

I then get the error `cp: omitting diretory '/home/temp/.'`

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by 'paste'?

Comment: What should be the "newfile"? Do you want to keep the old name and just add a suffix, or do you want to overwrite the file very time?

Comment: The source of your copy operation (`/home/temp/`) is a directory. It could work only if the destination (`/home/newfile.txt`) is also a directory.

Comment: Since you want to copy `/home/temp/oldfile` to `/home/newfile.txt`, `cp /home/temp/oldfile /home/newfile.txt` should be enough. Is it something that prevents you using it?

Comment: Read the [documentation of `cp`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/cp-invocation.html#index-cp).

Comment: @choroba I want to overwrite the file every time, so regardless of the old file name the file should just be newfile.txt

Comment: @axiac thanks, I'll have a look at the docs, and ask my system administrator if it's some administrator settings in windows.

Answer (score 1):

you should replace `.` with `*`:

```
cp /home/temp/* /home/newfile.txt
```

no need for the `-R` option; since you are copying only one file.